# How to avoid scrolling ListView when scrolling in map (MapBox) within ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When I swipe my map sometimes it is leading to scroll of ListView, so I would like to discover optimal solution for this situation.

I am using [flutter_map package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) and it has no **gestureRecognizers** property as other packages such as mapbox_gl and google_maps
My app structure:

```
 Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
          childred:[
            MapBox(), //[flutter_map package used here][1]
            GridView()
            ]
           )
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

we have `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` method to avoid the scrolling of listview.
we can use it like :

```
 Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
       physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          childred:[
            MapBox(),
            GridView()
            ]
           )
         );
```

This is restric to the scrolling of listview.

Comment: But I need scrollabilty of listview

Comment: you can wrap `Expanded` to `MapBox()`

Answer (score 0):

you should use `gestureRecognizers` property on [GoogleMap](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) or [MapBox](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl/example)

use this code hope it will work:

```
 gestureRecognizers:
   <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
   Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
    () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
   ),
].toSet(),
```

example for GoogleMap :

```
  GoogleMap(
     zoomControlsEnabled: false,
     mapType: MapType.normal,
     initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
     onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
       googleMapController.complete(controller);
     },
     onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
     gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
     new Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
         () => new EagerGestureRecognizer(),
        ),
      ].toSet(),
    ),
```

example for MapBox :

```
MapboxMap(
   accessToken: MapsDemo.ACCESS_TOKEN,
   onMapCreated: onMapCreatedOne,
   onStyleLoadedCallback: () => onStyleLoaded(controllerOne),
   initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
      target: center,
      zoom: 11.0,
    ),
   gestureRecognizers:
      <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
        Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
       () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
      ),
     ].toSet(),
   ),
```

Comment: Which package is it, I am using, flutter_map for mapbox [https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map]. And it has no gestureRecognizers parametr